# Definition of module

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

[image]

In the book's, The theory of numbers, S. Iyanaga. Chater I, Cohomology of groups.

What is the meaning of "module A"?

Thank you all.

Comment: [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29#Formal_definition). Note that the ring $R$ is being suppressed from the notation of your book.

Comment: And Automorphism of $M$; is automorphism of módules?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$